# MySql combining multiple tables to get one result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry to be so vague but I could really use some help with this one to get my head on straight. I cant seem to figure out the thought process behind this, any help or guidance would be appreciated!
I have a database whose schema is the following:

```
Customers(custID, name, firstOrderDate, city)
Items(itemID, description, size, color)
Orders(orderID, orderDate, custID)
ItemsOrdered(itemID, orderID, qty)
```

This is what I need to do:
-- Retrieve the id and name of the customers who have bought both an oxford and a tshirt in the same order.

I need to find all tshirt and oxford itemID's in Items. Go over to itemsordered and find the orderID of someone who bought them both in the same order. Then go to orders to find the customerID so I can go back over to customers and find that persons name. I hope this makes sense!

If someone could nudge me in the right direction I really need it! Im completely stumped on how to move forward on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you'll want to select all orders that contain items in both of those types, and tie that back to the customer.

I'm assuming for this that `Description` denotes what type of item it is - this should point you in the right direction though:

```
Select  Distinct C.CustId, C.Name
From    Orders          O
Join    Customers       C   On C.CustId = O.CustId
Where Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    ItemsOrdered IO
    Where   IO.OrderId = O.OrderId
    And     ItemId In
    (
        Select  ItemId
        From    Items
        Where   Description = 'TShirt'
    )
) 
And Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    ItemsOrdered IO2
    Where   IO2.OrderId = O.OrderId
    And     ItemId In
    (
        Select  ItemId
        From    Items
        Where   Description = 'Oxford'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Siyual! What if I wanted it to do the same for separate orders? Meaning they didnt have to buy them both in the same order to appear.

Comment: change the AND to OR in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    c.custID, c.name 
FROM 
    Customers AS c 
    INNER JOIN orders AS o 
    ON c.custID = o.custID
    INNER JOIN ItemsOrdered AS ioTshirts
    ON ioTshirts.orderID = o.orderID
    INNER JOIN ItemsOrdered as ioOxfords
    ON ioOxfords.orderID = o.orderID
    INNER JOIN Items tshirts
    ON ioTshirts.itemID = tshirts.itemID
    INNER JOIN Items oxfords
    ON ioOxfords.itemID = oxfords.itemID
WHERE
    tshirts.description like '%tshirt%' AND
    oxfords.description like '%oxford%'
GROUP BY
    c.custID
```